# unable to parse date string of format like 2013-09-17T05:15:27.947

Tags: c#, .net, parsing, datetime

I am trying to parse date of format:

> 2013-09-17T05:15:27.947

This is my code

```
String MessageRecieptDate = messageReceiptDate.Replace("T", " ").Remove(messageReceiptDate.Length-4);
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MessageRecieptDate, "dd MMM", culture);
```

But its giving some format exception every time. Seems I am missing something basic.

Comment: `ParseExact` will be more performant than `Parse`, but you must provide a matching string format.  You could just call `Parse`.

Comment: What is the “some format exception”?

Comment: @DourHighArch don't be so naive, had the question not been understandable. guys here could not have answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What should work :

```
//without ParseExact
var t1= DateTime.Parse(dt);

//you don't know how many milliseconds will be in your string, 
//and want absolutely use ParseExact anyway
var t2= DateTime.ParseExact(dt.PadRight(27, '0'), "o", culture);

//you know you'll always have 3 chars for milliseconds.
var t3= DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fff", culture);
```

Comment: i am not sure how many chars will be in ticks, so is there any way than providing format strings with f,ff,fff?

Comment: @ay89 see my second version. `PadRight` will add the necessary number of '0' at the end of your string. But honestly, if your string is not "exact", it's a little be weird to use `ParseExact`, you should use `Parse`...

Answer (score 10):

I have no idea why you're using `"dd MMM"` as format string, when your date is `"2014-02-03T19:00:00"`. There two formats have nothing in common.

Proper format string for your input is `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`:

```
string value = "2014-02-03T19:00:00";
DateTime dateValue = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: oh, i thought it was the output format, but it format of input string. thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

*Well*, [Marcin's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18698109/447156) are quite right but I want to point the root of your problem.

When you write,

```
string MessageRecieptDate = messageReceiptDate.Replace("T", " ").Remove(messageReceiptDate.Length-4);
```

Actually, you remove too much on your string. After this line your string will be like;

```
2014-02-03 19:0
```

Try to use `Remove(messageReceiptDate.Length - 3);` instead. This will make your string `2014-02-03 19:00` which is exactly we want.

Then you should use `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm` format which matches exactly with `2014-02-03 19:00`.

```
string messageReceiptDate = "2014-02-03T19:00:00";
string MessageRecieptDate = messageReceiptDate.Replace("T", " ").Remove(messageReceiptDate.Length - 3);
IFormatProvider culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MessageRecieptDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm", culture);
Console.WriteLine(dt);
```

Output will be;

```
2/3/2014 7:00:00 PM
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/hZnj35).

Comment: Actually, the output from this code is:
`03/02/2014 19:00:00`. Does this depend on local settings?

Comment: @dzookatz Yes, this totally depends on your current culture date format settings.

Answer (score 2):

Your string format is completely wrong:

You need to specify a format that matches the input string, i.e.: `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"`

```
 string MessageReceiptDate = "2014-02-03T19:00:00";
 var datex = DateTime.ParseExact(MessageReceiptDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", culture);
```

Answer (score 2):

use [DateTime.TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b85w22.aspx)

```
DateTime dateValue;
string dateString = "2013-09-17T05:15:27.947";
string[] formats= {"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss"};
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, formats, 
                              new CultureInfo("en-US"), 
                              DateTimeStyles.None, 
                              out dateValue))
{
   //parsing successful
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MessageRecieptDate, "dd MMM", culture);
```

has the wrong date format.

It should be something like:

```
dt = DateTime.ParseExact(MessageRecieptDate, "yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss", culture);
```